# (PYTHON) How do I import the only class within a file correctly?

Tags: python, file, class, import

Well I've made a simple class that could be helpful for multiple purposes, so naturally, I want to import it to other files. But the thing is, that it is only one class in the file, and I'm sure that this is the most basic thing ever, but there's something I'm missing because I don't know how to import the file and have it behaving as the class that is inside it.

I have inside of strool.py:

```py
class strool:
    def __init__(self, *parameters)
        # definition of object
    def other_functions():
        # etc, etc
```

The problem is that if I import the file with `import strool`, I have to do `strool.strool` to access the class, and that just doesn't make sense. I know how to make some workarounds like `import strool as s` (for less typing) or, `from strool import strool`, but I feel that those ways aren't the intended ones, and it doesn't feel *pythonic* when there's **only one** class in the file.

I haven't found any info on ***this*** specific problem so I've tried to change the name of the class to __main__, __init__ `(it might be a dumb thing to try, but this kind of guessing sometimes works lol)`. I've tried to move the methods out of the class and place them directly into the file like:

Inside of strool.py:

```
def __init__(self, *parameters)
    # definition of object
def other_functions():
    # etc, etc
```

and `(logically because I'm posting the question)` it didn't work. So, the question is:

What do I have to do in a python file to be able to import **its only** inner class directly, using just `import strool` to access the inner class with just `strool`?

Comment: `from strool import strool` is absolutely fine. There is no special syntax for when there is only one class (or name) defined in a module. You can do `from strool import *` to the same effect, of course, but star imports are discouraged.

Comment: I see. I guess using `from module import *` there might be conflicts between different methods/classes/variables from different modules that might share name. Beyond that, is there any other problem? @LevLevitsky

Comment: I think you're right, that would be the main reason. Also it makes it harder to track where a name comes from, to read the code and analyze it with tools.

Answer (score 2):

I upvoted the answer from @journy because the advice is correct.  Use: `from strool import Strool`

I want to clarify that both `import <module>` and `from <module> import <something>` will always load the entire module into memory.  The difference between the two is which variable name gets loaded into the current namespace.

So the premise of trying to "import the only class within a file" isn't really correct.  The whole module is loaded (and cached) and then `from` import will assign the class name into globals.

Comment: I didn't know that the whole module was loaded no matter what. Too often I define the specific <something> I need for my program thinking that it'll use less resources. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

It is more pythonic to begin your class names with capital letter. In this case, your module name is `strool.py`, you can define your class as:

```
class Strool:
    pass
```

Then import your class:

```
from strool import Strool
```